# Merging fat32 partition on external hard drive connected to ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, hard-drive, external-hdd

I have WD 160 GB hard drive and i have formatted it to fat32 file system i want to merge all multiple FAT32 file system partition to make it one. how do i do it on ubuntu 12.04LTS. Would also like to know if FAT 32 is good for sharing data between windows and linux systems and how to shrink "extended" partition on external hard [image]drive. 
Any help will be appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

Due to the craziness with that partition table, I would recommend backing up any data you might have and then just deleting all partitions and making a new one. GPartEd can format the drive to be one 160GB FAT32 partition. If you want to keep that Linux Swap partition, create two partitions.

I don't think FAT32 is a good format for sharing data, because it has a hard file-size limit of 4GB. With larger file sizes (particularly video data files) becoming commonplace. You will run into this limit frequently. NTFS is now read/write supported on Linux, so you can use it, or even mount Ext3 partitions on Windows.